# Filter a column and get the sum of another

Tags: excel, vba, count

Hello I have a code that does a vlookup on a column, but I am having an issue editing the last part of the code to do a count. Basically it should filter the two options in column D, get a sum from column I and put the total count in another sheet in the same workbook. Here is the code for better understanding:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Calculate()

Dim count_DL As Integer, count_IDL As Integer, wbMetrics As Workbook

    Sheets("PS").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],Regulares!C[6]:C[8],3,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Temp Activos'!C[3]:C[5],3,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Temp JA'!C[3]:C[5],3,0),VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Temp Fit'!C[3]:C[5],3))))"
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D:D")
    Range("D:D").Select

    Columns("I:I").Select
        Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    Range("J2").Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "="
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-1])"
    Range("J3").Select

    'count_DL = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range("D:D"), "DL")
    'count_IDL = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range("D:D"), "IDL")

    'Worksheets("Resultados").Range("B13") = count_DL
    'Worksheets("Resultados").Range("C14") = count_IDL

    Sheets("Resultados").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use Select. Use:

```
 With Sheets("PS").Range("D2")

      .FormulaR1C1= _
           =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],Regulares!C[6]:C[8],3,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Temp Activos'!C[3]:C[5],3,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Temp JA'!C[3]:C[5],3,0),VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Temp Fit'!C[3]:C[5],3))))"
      .AutoFill Destination:=Range("D:D")

 End With
```

and tweek it for the rest of your code. You pretty much never want to do anything using Select.

Secondly, your problem is that you are defining count_IDL and count_DL as integers. CountIf returns a Double, so you should define your variables that way.

Also, if you want Resultados to be the active sheet when you're done, you should use Sheets("Resultados").Activate

Comment: I get an Autofill method of Range class failed on this line `.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D:D")` Can you also specify the line where you say that Countif returns a Double?

Comment: I figured out why AutoFill is failing. Your source range must be the beginning of your fill range. That's something that isn't specified in it's MSDN write up. You should change your range to "D2:Dx" with x being however many rows you wish to autofill.

When you use the CountIf Method of the WorkSheetFunction Object, it will return a Double. It's in the write up for CountIf  here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839272(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Does the x in the "D2:Dx" have to be declared? If so, how? Im still trying to figure out the countif...

Comment: The x not a variable, just an example. If you want to autofill from D2 to D15, You would use the range "D2:D15". If you wanted to autofill to D30, you would use the range "D2:D30". If you want to go to the last row in the sheet, use "D2:D1048576".

Comment: When you use CountIf, the result that CountIf returns to you is in the form of a Double, not an Integer. Honestly, it shouldn't affect your results most of the time because the return of your CountIf will be convertible to an Integer 99% of the time, and the code as you have it should work. Do you have the single quotes before your count_DL and count_IDL lines as shown in your OP?

Comment: Ok got it... and actually sorry for the confusion here... My mistake in not explaining things properly what I need is the sum of hours in column I for both DL and IDL from column D... If I were to do this manually it would go something like this: 
1 filter column D by DL only and get the sum of hours from column I
2 filter column D by IDL only and get the sum of hours from column I
I would like to change my code so it can do that

Comment: I was just looking at the sumif method, but cant figure out how to plug that in to my code... And also looking into my autofill issue it will vary from month to month so I could start at D2 but the last will vary from one month to the other...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56378/discussion-between-asp8811-and-william).